# WSHLST app Error in Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have downloaded WSHLST from GitHub and followed the project setup in Azure mobile services. It's worked with Windows Phone, but when i build against Android throws the below error page.

Note: The errors are something related to 'Android.Content.Context' error.
[image: WSHLSTERROR]

For the below code it shows the error. Kindly find below the image for your reference. Kindly help me to execute the solution in android.

```
var picker = new MediaPicker(activity.Activity);
```

[image: MediaPickerError]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think WshLst and the assemblies in that repo were built before the Xamarin 2.0 launch. During that launch, Xamarin changed their strong name signing key - so that is probably the problem you are hitting.

If you want to use that code, then you'll need to update several assemblies/dependencies to get that working - see some info on threads like:

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1476/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-android-4-6-0
- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1475/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-ios-6-2-0

That code is almost a year old now - and given the fast pace of development of all 3 of Xamarin, Azure Mobile Services and MvvmCross, then I expect you'll need to update quite a lot to make this codebase live again - but doing so could be very useful for others who follow you.